# Design a highly optimized datastructure to perform three operations insert, delete and getRandom

Tags: optimization, data-structures

I just had a software interview. One of the questions was to design any datastructure with three methods insert, delete and getRandom in a highly optimized way. The interviewer asked me to think of a combination of datastructures to design a new one. Insert can be designed anyway but for random and delete i need to get the position of specific element. He gave me a hint to think about the datastructure which takes minimum time for sorting.

Any answer or discussion is welcomed....

Comment: should getRandom return a random element or is it random access?

Comment: `typedef std::deque<sometype> datastructure_t;` Insert, random access, delete, got all covered. You're probably not going to need any faster than O(1).

Comment: a random element should be returned..

Comment: @Damon: deque has "linear time insertion and removal of elements in the middle" (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html). So if one needs to remove an arbitrary element from the datastructure, it will be O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `t` be the type of the elements you want to store in the datastructure.
Have an extensible array `elements` containing all the elements in no particular order. Have a hashtable `indices` that maps elements of type `t` to their position in `elements`.

- Inserting `e` means

  - add `e` at the end of `elements` (i.e. push_back), get its position `i`
  - insert the mapping `(e,i)` into `indices
- deleting `e` means

  - find the position `i` of `e` in `elements` thanks to `indices`
  - overwrite `e` with the last element `f` of `elements`
  - update `indices`: remove the mapping `(f,indices.size())` and insert `(f,i)`
- drawing one element at random (leaving it in the datastructure, i.e. it's `peek`, not `pop`) is simply drawing an integer `i` in `[0,elements.size()[` and returning `elements[i]`.

Assuming the hashtable is well suited for your elements of type `t`, all three operations are O(1).

Be careful about the cases where there are 0 or 1 element in the datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

A tree might work well here. Order log(n) insert and delete, and choose random could also be log(n): start at the root node and at each junction choose a child at random (weighted by the total number of leaf nodes per child) until you reach a leaf.

Comment: I think you mean a balanced BST else delete will take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure which takes the least time for sorting is sorted array.

get_random() is binary search, so O(log n).

insert() and delete() involve adding/removing the element in question and then resorting, which is O(n log n), e.g. horrendous.

I think his hint was poor.  You may have been in a bad interview.

Comment: I understand "the datastructure which takes minimum time for sorting"  as "a data structure used in a O(n log n) sorting algorithm". In which case a binary tree indeed allows all three operations to be performed in O(log n), as suggested by @AlexWilson.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is that you can use some balaced version of tree like Red-Black trees. This will give O(log n) insertion and deletion time.
For getting random element, may be you can have a additional hash table to keep track of elements which are in the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

It might be [Heap (data structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)